# Estimation of server cabinate weight?

Tags: rack

Anyone got any idea what the aprox weight of a half size server rack (with stuff in it) would be?

Assume a 24U dell rack with 4x1Us and 4x2Us, switch, kvm unit, cables and a couple of low end UPS devices inside.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to move a rack between two locations.  This question may help: http://serverfault.com/questions/49998/advice-on-moving-a-machine-room-to-a-new-location/

Comment: intersting link thanks. Actually it was to see if the lift in our building can handle the whole rack in one go.

Comment: out of interest, Even though we were within the weight limit. We broke the lift.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.dell.com/content/topics/topic.aspx/global/products/pedge/topics/en/config_calculator?c=us&l=en&cs=555

Have a look at the capacity planner - it should show you a weight calculation by model, as well as quite a few other things